# How do I create a SOAP request directly by parsing the WSDL file?

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl

I was tasked to create Perl scripts which can create an XML payload with supplied parameters and invoke a SOAP call, then read the response and parse parameters to provide for the next use. I am pretty new at SOAP messaging.

I have a WSDL file based on which I am able to manually create an XML SOAP message, but I do not think this is the right way how to do it. I also do not understand how to invoke a SOAP call. Yes, I can read the documentation and I have read it a couple of times, but I want to ask if there is possibility to create a SOAP request directly by parsing the WSDL file. What are the possibilities for this topic?

I only have a description or pseudocode for what it should do and I am quite new at SOAP/Web services. Do you have any link to what could be useful for me?

Comment: [SOAP::Lite](http://p3rl.org/SOAP::Lite), [XML::Compile](http://p3rl.org/XML::Compile)

Comment: Try [SOAP::WSDL](http://search.cpan.org/~swalters/SOAP-WSDL-3.003/lib/SOAP/WSDL.pm).Very usefull and easy to use.

Comment: I thought that SOAP::WSDL is obsolete ... maybe i misread it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [XML::Compile::WSDL11](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/XML-Compile-WSDL11-3.04/lib/XML/Compile/WSDL11.pod#Initializing_SOAP_operations_via_WSDL)

From the docs:

```
use XML::Compile::WSDL11 (); 

# once in your program
my $wsdl   = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new('def.wsdl');

# XML::Compile::Schema refuses to follow "include" and
# "import" commands, so you need to invoke them explicitly.
# $wsdl->addWSDL('file2.wsdl');            # optional
# $wsdl->importDefinitions('schema1.xsd'); # optional

# once for each of the defined operations
my $call   = $wsdl->compileClient('GetStockPrice');

# see XML::Compile::SOAP chapter DETAILS about call params
my $answer = $call->(%request);
```